# How to prevent access to a class from within a namespace?

Tags: c#, namespaces, access-modifiers

How can I prevent use of a class from outside its namespace in C#?

For example, I have two namespaces. One defines a data model class, the other defines a data model class which inherits the first. The second namespace also defines a utility class which is the only class to be allowed to use the second data model class..

```
namespace A
{
    public class ModelA {} // can be used by any class
}

namespace B
{
    class ModelB : ModelA {} // can only be used by Utility

    public class Utility
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            var item = new ModelB {};
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

By implementing the following code in another class library or project, I would like the effect indicated by the comments...

```
namespace C
{
    public class Stuff
    {
        public void DoThings()
        {
            var a = new ModelA(); // this should work
            var b = new ModelB(); // this should not work
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make ModelB as private class in Utility.

Comment: Having tested this one step further, I've realised the change I just made to the post is probably correct. The default access modifier for a class is internal, so this should work.

Comment: You want to prevent Utility from using ModelA, right?

Comment: @dzianis-karpuk No. The code comments explain what should be accessible.

Comment: @MattW `internal` restricts to the same _assembly_. meaning: the class cannot be accessed from other assemblies, but from other namespaces of the same assemblys. which _might_ be what you wanted, but not what you asked.

Comment: @franz-gleichmann Yes, that's what I read, but when I tried it, the compiler complains if I try to reference ModelB outside of its namespace.

Comment: @MattW well, i just tried, and mine doesn't. my guess is that you _are_ trying to access it from another assembly (=another project in the same solution)

Comment: @franz-gleichmann Dang. You're right. Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can not add a `private` access modifier to classes that are directly contained in a namespace.

You can however make `ModelB` a private nested class:

```cs
namespace A
{
    class ModelA {} // can be used by any class
}

namespace B
{
    class Utility
    {
        private class ModelB : ModelA {} // can only be used by Utility
        
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            var item = new ModelB {};
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

which means that, like any other private property, it cannot be accessed outside of the `Utility`-class

Comment: Thanks - what do you think of the update to the posted code?